# Why doesn't regex '.+' work as expected?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

```
[root@localhost opt]# cat cfg
key = value
[root@localhost opt]# grep 'key\s*=\s*.+' cfg
[root@localhost opt]#
```

My intent is: the `=` sign may be followed by zero or more spaces, but must be followed one or more non-space characters.

Why doesn't it output the line `key = value`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observe:

```
$ grep 'key\s*=\s*.+' cfg
$ grep 'key\s*=\s*.\+' cfg
key = value
$ grep -E 'key\s*=\s*.+' cfg
key = value
```

In Basic Regular Expressions (BRE, the default), `+` means a plus sign.  As a GNU extension, one can signal one-or-more-of-the-previous-character using `\+`.  This is also true of `?`, `{`, `|`, and `(`.  Unless escaped with a backslash, these are all treated a ordinary characters under BRE.

The rules change if you use Extended Regular Expressions, `-E`.  For ERE, the backslash isn't needed and a plain `+` means one-or-more-of-the-previous-character.  Under ERE, `\+` means a plain normal plus sign.

Comment: Technically, `\+` is a feature of *enhanced* BREs (like we need even more flavors of REs in POSIX). `grep` appears to pass the `REG_ENHANCED` flag to `regcomp()`; otherwise, you would have to use `{1,}` like `expr` does.

Comment: But `grep -E 'key\s*=\s*.+'` does match `key = ` (with one or more trailing space) as that's a `=` followed by 0 space (which matches `\s*`) followed by one space character (which matches `.`). Also note that `\s`/`\S` are not standard/portable. You'd want `grep -Ex 'key\s*=\s*\S.*'` or `grep -E '^key\s*=\s*\S'` to force at least one non-space after the `=`. `[[:space:]]` is the standard equivalent of `\s`, though here, `[[:blank:]]` may make more sense.

Comment: Note that `\+` in BRE is a GNU extension. In standard BREs, `+` is written `\{1,\}`.

Comment: @chepner Yes.  Answer updated to note that `\+` under BRE is a GNU extension.  (When originally posted, this question was tagged Linux,  I see that that tag has since been removed.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see that you have posted (+1) a thorough exploration of this regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
key\s*=\s*.+
```

is GNU ERE syntax (assuming you want `\s` to match any spacing character, and `+` to match one or more of the preceding atom), so you'd need the GNU implementation of `grep` and pass the `-E` option.

However, even then that wouldn't make much sense

First

```
grep 'key\s*=\s*.+'
```

is functionaly equivalent to

```
grep 'key\s*=\s*.'
```

Because if a string matches `anything.+`, then it also matches `anything.` and vis-versa.

Also a spacing character is also a character. Since `\s*` matches **0** or more spacing characters, `key\s*=\s*.` is functionaly equivalent to `key\s*=.` (lines that contain `key<optional-spaces>=<one-character-space-or-not>`).

Here you want:

```
grep 'key\s*=\s*\S'
```

to ask for at least one non-spacing character to be found on the right of the `=`, which is functionaly equivalent to:

```
grep 'key\s*=.*\S'
```

Note that it matches `key = foo` but also `nonkey = foo`. If you want the `key` to be only found at the beginning of the line, you need to ask for it with the `^` anchor:

```
grep '^key\s*=.*\S'
```

Or use `-x` for the regexp to match the whole line:

```
grep -x 'key\s*=.*\S.*'
```

Note that the standard equivalent of `\s` is `[[:space:]]` (`[^[:space:]]` for `\S`).

Another way to address the requirement would be to use extended operators found in some regexps like the PCRE ones to prevent back-tracking.

`key=\s*.` matches `key=`  because the regexp engine has `\s*` go greedily through the space characters after the `=`, finds 1 and then realises it can't match the `.` as it reached the end of the line, and then *back-tracks* to try with fewer matches of `\s` (0 in that case) so the next `.` can match (here a space character).

With PCRE, like when using the `-P` option with GNU `grep`, you can write:

```
 grep -P '^key\s*=(?>\s*).'
```

That `(?>...)` syntax prevents back-tracking. So the `\s*` will eat as many spacing characters as possible without being able to backtrack, so will only match if there's at least one non-spacing character after the spaces.

```
$ printf 'key=%s\n' '' ' ' ' a' | grep '^key\s*=\s*.'
key=
key= a
$ printf 'key=%s\n' '' ' ' ' a' | grep -P '^key\s*=(?>\s*).'
key= a
$ printf 'key=%s\n' '' ' ' ' a' | grep '^key\s*=.*\S'
key= a
```